# Is it possible to find an element with accessible role and name?

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver, accessibility, selenide

I have an html structure like:

```html
<section aria-labelledby="123">
  <h2 id="123">Title</h2>
</section>
```

The html [`section`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section) element has an implicit [`region`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/region_role) accessibility role

Is there something like `byRole` selenide selector that would find the element by role and name?

e.g.:

```java
byRole('region', 'Title')
```

Or can it be grabbed using xpath?

Comment: Nice approach to test from an AT perspective! While there is a `getAriaRole` method on WebElement, the [`By`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html) does not seem to have an ARIA locating mechanism.
XPath wont help you at all, because the role and the accessible name need to be computed. You’d need to create a selector that takes into account all possible ways to assign role, and accessible name. There might be a library for that, though.

Answer (score 0):

Selenide doesn't have built-in function for getting element by role and title, however, it can be easily done with xPath

For example, this locator would point for your section element with `role` where child exists with text that contains Title.

```java
$x("//*[@role='region' and .//*[contains(.,'Title')]]")
```

or you can do it by using `filter` from `Stream API`

```java
$$("[role=region]").stream().filter(el -> el.innerText().contains("Title"))
.findFirst().get();
```

Comment: It kind of works, but not really. Will  `@role='region'` find elements with tag `<section>` without specifying the role attribute directly? Also, will aria-label work with `contains(.,'Title')`?

Comment: Xpath logic is: find any element, which attribute role equals 'region' and that contains any child with text `Title`. If you doesn't care about role tag, you can specify `//*[@role and .//*[contains(.,'Title')]]` .
Try it there https://inputnum.w3spaces.com/saved-from-Tryit-2023-10-06.html